# Extracting JSON_VALUE out of json array

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server

This works fine if we have just one object:

`SELECT JSON_VALUE('{"Name": "Test"}', '$.Name');`
Output: Test

How can I get every `Name` property from json array in MS SQL?

`SELECT JSON_VALUE('[{"Name": "Test"},{"Name": "Test2"}]', '$.Name');`
Expected Output: 2 rows, Test and Test2

Comment: As you're wanting _rows_ as output you'll need to use `OPENJSON` with `CROSS APPLY` instead of the scalar functions (like `JSON_VALUE`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're wanting *rows* as output [you'll need to use `OPENJSON` (maybe with `CROSS APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)) instead of the scalar functions (like `JSON_VALUE`).

#### If your JSON is in a scalar T-SQL variable or parameter (e.g. `@jsonText`) then you can do this:

```sql
DECLARE @jsonText nvarchar(max) = N'[{"Name": "Test"},{"Name": "Test2"}]';

SELECT
    j."Name"
FROM
    OPENJSON( @jsonText ) WITH (
        "Name" nvarchar(256) '$.Name'
    ) AS j;
```

[image]

---

#### If it's in a table column, use `CROSS APPLY`, like so:

```sql
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    JsonBlargh nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @t ( JsonBlargh ) VALUES
( N'[{"Name": "Test"},{"Name": "Test2"}]' ),
( N'[{"Name": "Test3"},{"Name": "Test4"}]' ),
( N'[{"Name": "Test5"},{"Name": "Test6"}]' );

-----------

SELECT
    j."Name"
FROM
    @t AS t
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON( t.JsonBlargh/*, '$.Name'*/ ) WITH (
        "Name" nvarchar(256) '$.Name'
    ) AS j
```

[image]